# Refreshing HTML frame of parent window doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This line `window.opener.parent.frames[1].location.reload(true);` works fine in IE7. In Google Chrome v33 it does nothing. It is meant to refresh the 2nd frame of the parent window. Both of these windows are popup windows containing HTML frames. (In case anyone is wondering why it uses frames, this application was written about 12 years ago.)

**Update:** the error Chrome Developer Tools provides is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

So the issue must be with the `window.opener.parent.frames[1]` part

Comment: is your parent frame in a different domain?

Comment: As an addition to jnoreiga's comment, Chrome treats also local files (i.e. when using file protocol) as cross-domain sources.

Comment: @jnoreiga if you're referring to the domain name, no it's the same

Comment: What happens if instead of doing `frames[1].location.reload` you try something like `frames[1].src = frames[1].src;`? With perhaps an extra parameter for cache-busting.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it doesn't do anything in Chrome and in IE it says "frames.1.src is null or not an object". In the code it's written exactly like how you typed it though with the [] around 1

Comment: @user1985189 interesting. How the frame source is specified - via src attribute? Also does `frames[1].setAttribute('src',frames[1].getAttribute('src'));` makes a difference?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes frame source is specified via src. And not sure what you mean with that line of code. Are you suggesting to replace `frames[1].location.reload(true)` with that?

Comment: Yes, instead of `.frames[1].location.reload(true);` try `.frames[1].setAttribute('src',frames[1].getAttribute('src'));`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter no now it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined". The issue I think is in the first part. See my update above

Comment: in that case - instead of using `.frames[1]` can u give the frame an id and use `.getElementById(...)` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter afraid that didn't work either. Chrome didn't even give an error... it just didn't do anything

Comment: `window.opener.parent.frames[1]` means that `window.opener` is an `iframe`, which has either `frameset` and `frame`s, or more than one `iframe`. If this is not the situation, remove `parent` from the chain. Notice also what I've said in my previous comment.

Comment: @Teemu the parent window does have multiple frames within a frameset. I don't understand the relevance of local files here. Care to explain further?

Comment: If you're running the code locally, it will not work in Chrome.

Comment: @Teemu ah ok. Well that's not the case. It's running on WebLogic Server